# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, cloud

I am using SAP crystal report Version=13.0.2000.0 ,visual studio 2010 and SAP crystal report runtime engine for .net framework 4(64-bit)
I am getting following error in crystal report loading while deploying the project in Cloud while report is shown in design mode.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

Comment: if you search for "bobj" in all your source code, do you see anything?

Answer (score 3):

**This will work 100%**

I solved it and anyone find another solution rather than below one, Please post it. I am using **Visual Studio 2013**.

**1)** Go to this Path : **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319** .

**2)** Copy folder name crystalreportviewers13 , and iclude it in your web project.

**3)** At the Head form where you load and have the crystal report viewer call this java script file.

```
  <head runat="server">
      <title>View Report</title>
      <script lang="javaScript" type="text/javascript" src="crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js">
      </script> 
  </head>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am using SAP crystal report Version=13.0.2000.0 ,visual studio 2010 and SAP crystal report runtime engine for .net framework 4(64-bit) I am getting following error in crystal report loading while deploying the project in Cloud while report is shown in design mode.

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

After that i have reinstall crystal reports for visual studio 2010.

Now its Working Good..

Please try it..

Answer (score 2):

Just try effecting full postback on submit for viewing the report.
It worked fine for me with each report refreshing with new data on change of parameters and pressing submit button.

If you are using Ajax, then contain reportviewer part in update panel and attach a trigger to 'Submit' button. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi also get the some error, in my development server crystal report works well, but in production getting wrong with 'bobj' is undefined. I have copied aspnet_client from c:\inetpub\www into my site directory. But still showing page error 'bobj' is undefined.

After trying and investigating, my Default Web Site directory in IIS not in c:\inetpub\www, but in other direcory, so I copy aspnet_client from c:\inetpub\www to Default Web Site directory and also in my site directory. And 'bobj' is undefined does not exist anymore. It works well.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue.  It was working on test server but not production server. On production I had my application located in a folder within the **www** folder i.e `c:\inetup\www\Collateral` and setup IIS7 to use the Default Web Site node as my root folder pointing to the Collateral as a virtual directory.
 I suspected that this was what was causing the bobj undefined error and so I copied the `aspnet_client` folder into the `Collateral` folder and it worked.