# Web Application Error 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am having a trouble in displaying a Crystal Report in a ASP.NET page. The error is

```
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined
```

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and Crystal Report 13.0.5.891.

I have seen this already [Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'bobj' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871155/microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-bobj-is-undefined) but none of the comments helped me.

I also added some items in Web.config file:

```
<sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
    <sectionGroup  name="crystalReports">
    <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304,  Custom=null" />
    <section  name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
    </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <businessObjects>
  <crystalReports>
<rptBuildProvider>
<add embedRptInResource="true" />
</rptBuildProvider>
<crystalReportViewer>
<add  key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers" />
</crystalReportViewer>
</crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

I also copied the folder crystalreportviewers to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319. But I still get the bobj undefined error.

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm having the same problem, despite copying the aspnet_client folder into wwwroot and into the project folder as well.

Comment: I followed the instructions here http://www.mahadera.com/error-0x800a1391-javascript-runtime-error-bobj-is-undefined/

Answer (score 0):

Copy this folder (crystalreportviewers13) which exists in this path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319
and paste it in your project:

[image]